# How to remove the ?q= from search query url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I have a search field in my app, while make search the url become `/search/?q=12344/` but instead i need `/search/12344/` how i can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change you urls.py file to make that happen.

```
url(r'^search/(?P<search_term>[\w-]+)/$', views.search)
```

and in your views file where you catch that url request you will need to add another parameter after request like this

```
def search(request, search_term):
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a `url` for the same and when a user enters anything in the search query just `redirect` it to your new `url` appending your query term to it.

For example :

```
url(r'^search/(?P<search_term>[\w-]+)/$', views.search)
```